# How to load a scene file, .scn from framework bundles

Tags: ios, objective-c, scenekit

I have a scene file, Tube.scn saved in a framework: "Build Phrases/Copy Bundle Resources"

[screenshot][1]

I am trying to load the file within the framework using the following:

```
NSString *filename = @"Tube";

NSString *path = [[NSBundle bundleForClass: [self class]] pathForResource: filename
                                                                   ofType: @"scn"];

NSError *error;
self.scene = [SCNScene sceneWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: path]
                            options: nil
                              error: &error];
```

but, both self.scene and error are nil.

However, if I moved the file to the main project and use the following, it would work fine.

```
self.scene = [SCNScene sceneNamed: @"Tube.scn"];
```

Does anyone have successfully loaded scene files within frameworks?

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle bundleForClass: [self class]] pathForResource: filename
                                                                   ofType: @"scn"];
```

Is `[self class]` above, a class which is part of the framework? If not, then may be you should try:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle bundleForClass: [<<X>> class]] pathForResource: filename
                                                                   ofType: @"scn"];
```

where: `<<X>>` is class which is part of the framework.

Comment: Yes, the [self class] class is part of the framework.  It's on the framework's Target Membership.

Comment: More info about the class and the framework:

framework's **Build Phases**
**Compile Sources**
  contains the class .m file
**Headers/Public**
  contains the class header file